# generate the right schema of an s3 aws bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have this list of paths, or locations, that represents the contents of an aws s3 bucket:

```
const keysS3 = [
                'platform-tests/',
                'platform-tests/datasets/',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/change_name_dtype.json',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/change_name_dtype_2.csv',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/random_data_stack.json',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/random_data_stack_0.csv',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/random_data_stack_1.csv',
                'platform-tests/datasets/random_csv_datasets/1/raw/random_data_stack_2.csv',
                'platform-tests/test-folder/',
                'README.md',
                'preprocessed_data.csv',
                'preprocessed_data2 copy.csv',
                'reg1.csv',
                'tested_demo.csv'
            ];
```

and I'm writing this code in Typescrtip:

```
let output = {};
let current: any;
for (const path of keysS3) {
                current = output;
                const segment = path.split('/');
                segment.forEach((value, index) => {
                    if (value !== '' && index + 1 < segment.length) {
                        if (!(value in current)) {
                            current[value] = {};
                        }
                        current = current[value];
                    } else {
                        current[value] = null;
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

to convert it to this schema, here is the output:

```
{
   "platform-tests":{
      "datasets":{
         "random_csv_datasets":{
            "1":{
               "raw":{
                  "change_name_dtype.json":null,
                  "change_name_dtype_2.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack.json":null,
                  "random_data_stack_0.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack_1.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack_2.csv":null
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "test-folder":{

      }
   },
   "README.md":null,
   "preprocessed_data.csv":null,
   "preprocessed_data2 copy.csv":null,
   "reg1.csv":null,
   "tested_demo.csv":null
}
```

but, the issue is that I'm getting this schema, which it has this extra field that has been added after each sub-folder

> "":null

```
{
   "platform-tests":{
      "":null,
      "datasets":{
         "":null,
         "random_csv_datasets":{
            "1":{
               "":null,
               "raw":{
                  "":null,
                  "change_name_dtype.json":null,
                  "change_name_dtype_2.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack.json":null,
                  "random_data_stack_0.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack_1.csv":null,
                  "random_data_stack_2.csv":null
               }
            },
            "":null
         }
      },
      "test-folder":{
         "":null
      }
   },
   "README.md":null,
   "preprocessed_data.csv":null,
   "preprocessed_data2 copy.csv":null,
   "reg1.csv":null,
   "tested_demo.csv":null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out empty elements on your `.split` as you are ending with a `/` so you will always end up with an empty array element at the end of your array.

`const segment = path.split('/').filter(Boolean);`

Comment: nop, it didn't help.
I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'datasets' of null`

Answer (score 0):

I simply solved it by adding this line of code:

```
 if (!(value in current)) {
     current[value] = value.includes('.') ? null : {};
}
```

To validate whether the value is a path or a file name.